# How can i use both combotree and tagbox of jeasyui jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, jquery-easyui

I am using comboTree feature of jeasyui plugin. Can anybody help how to I use tagBox feature of that plugin too, to show selected tree nodes?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 control-label">Category</label>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control easyui-combotree easyui-tagbox" name="product_category" id="cc" placeholder="Ex. : MTR red chilli">
    </div>
</div>
```

Query for it is

```
$('#cc').combotree({
    url: 'tree_data1.json',
    method: 'get',
    cascadeCheck: false,
    multiple: true,
    required: true,
    prompt: 'Select Categories'
});
```

Now i want use tagTree feature with it. How could i do.

Link for tag tree plugin is https://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=TagBox&theme=bootstrap&dir=ltr&pitem=TagBox%20with%20Autocomplete&sort=

Link for comboTree plugin is

https://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=bootstrap&dir=ltr&pitem=&sort=

I  want to make that selected item's view as tag type as in tagTree.